# SSRS hide parts of a table with multiple group if there is no rows

Tags: reporting-services

I searched through the internet and on stackoverflow for hours and did not find a solution for my problem.

I have a report in SSRS which contains a table with 3 imbricated groups inside. This report shows students for a given teacher. Each student is enrolled in subjects grouped by discipline. In sum, there is a dynamic detail row inside of a discipline group and this discipline group is inside a student group. So a student can have 3 courses in mathematics, 2 in geography and 2 in history.

When the user want to generate the report, he must provide a value for these parameters:

```
Int Year : View courses were followed in the year specified.
Int Center : Center number to which the user want to get students
Int TeacherID : ID specified by the user to obtain the list of students 
       under the supervision of a teacher with this ID.
Int exceeding percentage : Show only courses with the hours performed 
       that are beyond the number of hours initially planned.
```

So what I do is hide the detail row if the course have an exceeding percentage under the exceeding percentage specified in the parameter.

What I need is if there is no course rows, hide the discipline group. And if there is no discplines for a student, hide the student infos group. Here is a screencap of my report (in french I know). Groups are represented by colored boxes:

```
Red = Student infos
Green = Disciplines
Pink = detail row for courses
```

http://img109.imageshack.us/img109/5516/groupsv.png

Hope you guys understand my needs. I know I made mistakes because my english is not the best, but I will clarify anything as best as I can. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correct you wish to hide a parent level if it's child 'detail' row has no data in that.

I would right click the 'row group' in the lower left corner.  Select 'Visibility' and select 'Expression', do this the visiblity expression of:

```
=iif( Isnothing(Sum(Fields!Percentage.Value)) OR Sum(Fields.Percentage.Value) = 0, TRUE, FALSE)
```

If your sum of all the dependent child items isnothing, or zero, you should hide that grouping parent row by setting the 'hidden' attribute to true.

Comment: You are the man. Your answer inspired me a little variation for the solution. Thank you!

Comment: I am glad this helped you.  Sometimes child elements that are nested are difficult to reach for specific requirements.